# Getting unexpected ',', expecting => ban error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I'm getting this error from Ruby:

> `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting => ban = Ban.where(:banned => 1, expires < ?", current_time) ^

I also get this error:

> `undefined method 'expires' for #<Ban::ActiveRecord_Relation` if I remove the `:banned => 1,`

This is my code:

```
class Ban < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :unban
  def unban
    puts "starting unban"
    current_time = Time.now
    puts current_time
    ban = Ban.where(:banned => 1, "expires < ?", current_time)
    if current_time > ban.expires
      ban.update_attributes(:banned => 0)
      puts "worked"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've intermingled where clause condition types; one is hash conditions, and the other using replacement parameters.  You can go with the shorter approach, which uses a single string, like this:

```
ban = Ban.where("banned = 1 and expires < ?", current_time)
```

or separately, like this:

```
ban = Ban.where(banned: 1).where("expires < ?", current_time)
```

In this case, I would choose the first method; the added complexity of having 2 where clauses isn't offset by the convenience of using a hash condition this simple.

The query will retrieve multiple answers, so you can't directly access a single record.  This is why you get the error with `expires`.  You should also verify that the query has returned a record before trying to use data from it.  You can either try this:

```
if ban.length > 0 && current_time > ban.first.expires
```

or change the result of the query and the `if` statement to this:

```
ban = Ban.where("banned = 1 and expires < ?", current_time).first
if ban && current_time > ban.expires
```

Answer (score 2):

You should either use string or hash notation, i.e.:

```
Ban.where(banned: 1).where('expires < ?', current_time)
```

Also, as you are using `where`, it returns you a collection of records, not a single `Ban` instance, so use `ban.first.expires` (don't forget, that the result can be `nil` and you should probably check it too).

Comment: However I'm still getting the error that exists is undefined.

Comment: However I can't use the > symbol in a find can I?

Comment: @aidiah: just use `where` and `first`